# ethereum stack exchange DNS problem

Tags: discussion, support

Today i've tried to access to [ethereum.stackexchange.com](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com) many times and i got DNS error even if change the DNS settings or i change the pc. How to resolve that issue?

[image]

Comment: Question is a good example of a benefit of decentralization... like some of the answers here http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-would-i-explain-ethereum-to-a-non-technical-friend :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Today the DNS host Dyn, one of the biggest DNS companies was suffering a big DDoS attack. perhaps this incident affected stakexchange.

**read more at**

http://www.businessinsider.com/amazon-spotify-twitter-github-and-etsy-down-in-apparent-dns-attack-2016-10

Comment: i think ethereum is a subdomain so if this dns problem occurs i think it should affect the whole stackexchange isn't it?